# Unable to login through ssh. Permission denied public key

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

Hello I used to login from my terminal to my ec2 istance using this command

```
ssh -i mypemfile.pem ec2-user@my-ip
```

I have changed just the directory permission of my folder and and did this

```
sudo chmod -R  777 /home/ec2-user/
```

Now when I try to login it says

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

Please help me how Can I go back. I am not able to login now

Comment: I just did the same i was trying to repermisin a directory and typed `chmod -R 775 /` into the command line after i logged out i cant ssh backin any more :-(

Comment: You made your private ssh key readable/writable for every user. The ssh server probably doesn't like that. If you can't access your EC2 instance anymore, you probably have to contact Amazon support.

Comment: @YehudaSchwartz If you really did `chmod -R 775 /` then most likely not only your `ssh` is broken but much, much more. The often-heard advice in such cases is to reinstall because fixing a `chmod -R 775 /` isn't worth the effort. I wonder when people will eventually stop issuing this command... There is a reason why some files have these and some files have other permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar is there a backdoor for *amazon-ec2*, but you should find a way to log-in into your server and change the permissions of the `~/.ssh` directory and it's content as follow:

```
chmod go-w ~/
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/
```

See the topic "Permission denied (publickey)" within the section "Troubleshooting" of the article [Public and Private Keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) on the Ubuntu Documentation Wiki.

If the password authentication is not already disabled you can try to log-in by the following command ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15138/how-to-force-ssh-client-to-use-only-password-auth)):

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no user@host
```

Comment: i'm on DO i booted in recovery mode logged in through the console and tried this didnt help :-(

Comment: @YehudaSchwartz That might be because you did not only break your home directory with the `chmod -R` but also the complete system by supplying `/` as the starting directory.

Comment: so how can i fix???

Comment: @YehudaSchwartz, as PerlDuck [said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061107/unable-to-login-through-ssh-permission-denied-public-key?noredirect=1#comment1736900_1061107), probably you should reinstall the OS.